# How to take a picture of part of your desktop with opencv and Qt

Tags: c++, qt, opencv

Thanks in advance for the help.
So below I am trying to a create a snipping tool. I created a widget using Qt and made its almost transparent. The user uses its mouse to create a square of area they want to be copied. I am able to get it to copy a section, just not the write section. I used the getcursor function to get users cursors positiona and the final and start points of the square. I set my widget to my screen size then I then take a picture of the entire desktop (using the size of my widget window as my image size) using my  void  function. However the screen and images x,y values don't "overlap", instead of getting what is in the square the user draws, it gets some other square on the screen. Is there anyway to fix this?

```
Frame_Record::Frame_Record(QWidget* parent) : QWidget(parent)
{
    //this->setStyleSheet("background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0)");

    this->setWindowState(Qt::WindowFullScreen);
    this->setWindowOpacity(0.1);
    this->setStyleSheet("QWidget{background:#000000}");
    x_size = this->size().width();
    y_size = this->size().height();
    //cv::waitKey(0);
    //setAttribute(Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground);

    /*setWindowFlags(Qt::Window | Qt::FramelessWindowHint);
    setAttribute(Qt::WA_NoSystemBackground);
    setAttribute(Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground);
    //setAttribute(Qt::WA_PaintOnScreen);
    //setAttribute(Qt::transparent);
    setAttribute(Qt::WA_MouseNoMask,true);
    setAttribute(Qt::WA_MouseTracking,true);*/
}

void Frame_Record::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent* events)
{
    POINT start;
    GetCursorPos(&start);
    qDebug() << "Mouse pressed PRessed";
    x_start = start.x;
    y_start = start.y;
}

void Frame_Record::mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent* events)
{
    qDebug() << "Mouse unpressed";
    qDebug() << x_start;
    qDebug() << y_start;
    qDebug() << x_end;
    qDebug() << y_end;
    POINT end;
    GetCursorPos(&end);

    x_end = end.x;
    y_end = end.y;
    get_Image(y_size, x_size); //y then x   
    this->close();
}

void Frame_Record::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent* events)
{
    POINT end;
    GetCursorPos(&end);

    x_end = end.x;
    y_end = end.y;
    qDebug() << "mouse is moving";
}

void Frame_Record::get_Image(int screen_w, int screen_h)
{
    HBITMAP bitmap;
    cv::Mat pic;

    HDC hdcSys = GetDC(NULL);
    HDC hdcMem = CreateCompatibleDC(hdcSys);

    void* ptrBitmapPixels;

    BITMAPINFO bInfo;
    HDC hdc{};
    ZeroMemory(&bInfo, sizeof(BITMAPINFO));
    bInfo.bmiHeader.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
    bInfo.bmiHeader.biWidth = screen_w;
    bInfo.bmiHeader.biHeight = -screen_h;
    bInfo.bmiHeader.biPlanes = 1;
    bInfo.bmiHeader.biBitCount = 32;

    bitmap = CreateDIBSection(hdc, &bInfo, DIB_RGB_COLORS, &ptrBitmapPixels, NULL, 0);
    SelectObject(hdcMem, bitmap);

    pic =cv::Mat(screen_h, screen_w, CV_8UC4, ptrBitmapPixels, 0);
    BitBlt(hdcMem, 0, 0, screen_w, screen_h, hdcSys, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
    cv::Mat mod_pic(pic, cv::Range(x_start, x_end), cv::Range(y_start, y_end));

    // pic(cv::Rect(x_start, y_start, x_start - x_end, y_start - y_end));   
    // Mat matRef=matBitmap(Range(100,200), Range(100,200));
    //bitwise_not(matRef,matRef);

    cv::imshow("Title", mod_pic);
    cv::waitKey(0);
    cv::destroyAllWindows();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following code in Qt to take the screen

```
QScreen *screen = // init screen first (application.primaryScreen();)
QRect rect = screen->geometry();
// instead you can also use your x and y coordinates
QPixmap pixmap = screen->grabWindow(0, rect .x(), rect .y(), rect .width(), rect .height());
```

And then you can do what you want with `QPixmap`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. The cursor position relative to the desktop and the cursor position relative to the screen don't match up. So if I click lets say point (140,150) according to the getcursor() function it will be point like (100,120) on the image. So when I click and drag a square and then try to cut that section it still doesn't give the right section.

Comment: Then you can calculate the exact point from the given diffrence (140-40, 150-30 OR 100+40, 120+30), and now you should the correct position.